# How to add attachment when replying to an email using the microsoft-graph api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the [microsoft-graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview?toc=./toc.json&view=graph-rest-1.0). I want to add an attachment when [replying](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-reply?view=graph-rest-1.0) to a message.

I have tried to add the attachment in the request body but i did not work.

```
{ "attachments":[
  { 
    "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment", 
    "name":"image.png", 
    "contentBytes":"base64 string"
   }],
  "comment": "reply body"
}
```

Comment: When you say "it did not work", what does that mean?

Comment: I mean that i receive the reply without the attachment

Comment: Did you try providing the full path to the file?

Comment: the contentBytes only accepts base64 string. i also tried to add the hasAttachment property but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to [create a reply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-createreply?view=graph-rest-1.0), [add the attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-post-attachments?view=graph-rest-1.0), and then [send the message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-send?view=graph-rest-1.0). You cannot do this using the basic [`/reply`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-reply?view=graph-rest-1.0) endpoint.